# AWS CLI - Saving the full output as a log file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using the aws s3 cp command to upload files to my s3 bucket. I am using windows cmd for this and when I run the following command:

```
aws s3 cp "logs.txt" s3://test/logs.txt --debug > ./log_test.txt
```

With the debug flag I see a lot of relevant information which is showed in the cmd window but when I open the log_test.txt file I can only see one line (maybe not even one).

Is there a way to save the full output showed in my cmd screen into a file?
This issue also happens when an error occurs. So if my file is not uploaded correctly I can't debug what the error was. Which is the main pain point I have.

I have already tried adding the --output flag but this only allows you to change the format of the output which is still not saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store complete log, the one that you see when your run that command without redirection then you can use `&>` instead of `>` for unix based systems.

So it should look like

```
aws s3 cp "logs.txt" s3://test/logs.txt --debug &> ./log_test.txt
```

I am not 100% sure what is the Windows equivalent, but I think it is `2>` so you can try

```
aws s3 cp "logs.txt" s3://test/logs.txt --debug 2> ./log_test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Matus! Indeed that was the solution. At the end what I did was use the normal > to get the output and 2> to get the error and debug information.
The command ended up like this:
aws s3 cp "logs.txt" s3://test/logs.txt --debug > ./output.txt 2> ./error.txt